# incorrect count of unique text in awk

Tags: awk

I am getting the wrong counts using the `awk` below.  The unique text in `$5` before the `-` is supposed to be counted.

**input**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    1   15
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    2   16
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    3   16
chr1    1267394 1268196 chr1:1267394-1268196    TAS1R3-46|gc=68.2   553 567
chr1    1267394 1268196 chr1:1267394-1268196    TAS1R3-46|gc=68.2   554 569
chr1    9781175 9781316 chr1:9781175-9781316    PIK3CD-276|gc=63.1  46  203
chr1    9781175 9781316 chr1:9781175-9781316    PIK3CD-276|gc=63.1  47  206
chr1    9781175 9781316 chr1:9781175-9781316    PIK3CD-276|gc=63.1  48  206
chr1    9781175 9781316 chr1:9781175-9781316    PIK3CD-276|gc=63.1  49  207
```

**current output**

```
1
```

**desired output** (AGRN,TAS1R3, PIK3CD) are unique and counted

```
3
```

**awk**

```
awk -F '[- ]' '!seen[$6]++ {n++} END {print n}' file
```

Comment: I got `3`. Which version of `awk` are you using?

Comment: @hek2mgl: The `3` is a coincidence (the symptom described doesn't match the sample data); a different field is being counted, because the field-separator regex doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
awk -F '-| +' '!seen[$6]++ {n++} END {print n}' file
```

Your problem is that **when `' '` (a space) is included as *part* of a regex** to form `FS` (via `-F`) it **loses its special default-value behavior**, and **only matches spaces *individually* as separators**. 
That is, the default behavior of recognizing *runs* of whitespace (any mix of spaces *and tabs*) as a *single* separator no longer applies.

Thus, `[- ]` won't do as the field separator, because it **recognizes the empty strings between adjacent spaces as empty fields**.

You can verify this by printing the field count - based on your intended parsing, you're expecting **9** fields:

```
$ awk -F '[- ]' '{ print NF }' file
17  # !! 8 extra fields - empty fields

$ awk -F '-| +' '{ print NF }' file
9   # OK, thanks to modified regex
```

You **need alternation `-| +`** to ensure that *runs* of spaces are treated as a single separator; if tabs should also be matched, use `'-|[[:blank:]]+'`

Answer (score 2):

Including "-" in FS might be fine in some cases, but in general if the actual field separator is something else (e.g. whitespace, as seems to be the case here, or perhaps a tab), it would be far better to set FS according to the specification of the file format. In any case, it's easy to extract the subfield of interest. In the following, I'll assume the FS is whitespace.

```
awk '{split($5, a, "-"); if (!(count[a[1]]++)) n++ }
     END {print n}'
```

If you want the details:

```
awk '{split($5, a, "-"); count[a[1]]++}
     END { for(i in count) {print i, count[i]}}'
```

Output of the second incantation:

```
AGRN 3
PIK3CD 4
TAS1R3 2
```